# Bugzilla installation issue in apache2- Ubuntu

Tags: perl, ubuntu, apache2, bugzilla

When running

> sudo /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl mod_perl2

command to install mod_perl for installing bugzilla in apache2 Ubuntu. I got the following error. I have installed apache2 ,MySql and Perl.

```
Checking for                 CPAN (v1.81)     ok: found v1.960001 
Checking for                 YAML (any)       ok: found v0.84 
Checking for   ExtUtils-MakeMaker (v6.31)     ok: found v6.82 
Going to read '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Wed, 20 Nov 2013 19:08:54 GMT
Installing mod_perl2 version 2.000008...
Running install for module 'mod_perl2'
Running make for P/PH/PHRED/mod_perl-2.0.8.tar.gz
Checksum for /root/.cpan/source/authors/id/P/PH/PHRED/mod_perl-2.0.8.tar.gz ok

  CPAN.pm: Going to build P/PH/PHRED/mod_perl-2.0.8.tar.gz

Reading Makefile.PL args from @ARGV
no conflicting prior mod_perl version found - good.
************* WARNING *************

  Your Perl is configured to link against libgdbm,
  but libgdbm.so was not found.
  You could just symlink it to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdbm.so.3.0.0


************* WARNING *************

Next we need to know where the 'apxs' script is located. This script
provides a lot of information about the Apache installation, and makes
it easier to find things on your system. Normally it's located in the
same directory as the 'httpd' executable.

If you don't yet have Apache installed you can build Apache against
the Apache source code, but you won't be able to run the test suite (a
very important step). Therefore you may want to install Apache before
proceeding.


Please provide a full path to 'apxs' executable
(press Enter if you don't have it installed):  


Please provide the location of the Apache directory:  
[  error] Can't find dir ''
Please provide the location of the Apache directory:  
[  error] Can't find dir ''
```

Comment: is there a reason to not just sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-perl ?

Answer (score 5):

To resolve the perl lib issue, cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ then link libgdbm.so.3.0.0 to libgdbm.so. 
ln -s  libgdbm.so.3.0.0 libgdbm.so. 
That should clear up the first warning.

For the apxs issue, you need to install apache2-dev. 
on Ubuntu use the following command 
sudo apt-get install apache2-dev

Rerun and that should correct it.